# Rails. Association of the same line items in the cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need association of the same line items when they add in cart. Now I have new line item after every submit form. I try fix it use add_product in line item controller:

Line item controller:

```
def create
  @cart = current_cart
  @line_item = @cart.add_product(@product.id)    
end
```

Cart model

```
has_many   :line_items, dependent: :destroy 

def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
    if current_item
        current_item.quantity += line_item.quantity.to_i
    else
        current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    end
    current_item
end
```

Line item form partial render in show product page:

```
= form_for (@line_item) , remote: true do |f| 
    div class="input-group"
        = f.number_field :quantity, value: 1, class: "form-control", min: 1 
        div class="input-group-btn"
                = f.hidden_field :product_id, value: @product.id 
                = f.submit "Add to Cart"
```

But after submit form has error: "NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):"

How transfer @product.id from form to controller?

**UPD**
add @product in line_item controller

```
def create
  @product = Product.find(params[:line_item][:product_id])
  @cart = current_cart
  @line_item = @cart.add_product(@product.id)    
end
```

Comment: i think you can see this error because form itself not getting @product

Comment: no, @product in form is ok.

Comment: okay, try   @product = Product.find_by_id(params[:line_item][:product_id])

Comment: nothing. no error, no line_item in cart.

Comment: you can print product id at every step using puts "...#{@product.id}" so you can test where you lost it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must find @product in the create action of the controller (or in before_action) by the product_id from the params.
Something like:

```
@product = Product.find(params[:line_item][:product_id])
```

(though that's not very beautiful)

Comment: add     @product = Product.find(params[:line_item][:product_id]) in create action in line_item controller. error missing, but line_item not add in cart.

Comment: This code
current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
does not save record in db, you should use create instead of build to do this

Comment: new problem = new question. Thenks for help!